# Creating System.Object instance in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm experiencing a sort of bug in Unity, probably due to the fact I'm almost new to it:
I have a MonoBehaviour object that correctly lives in memory.
For sake of code organization, this object have two members of standard System.Object classes which needs to be created by a new call.

```
class A
{
     // ...
}
class B
{
    // ...
}
class Status : MonoBehaviour
{
    A m_AVar;
    B m_BVar;

    public A AVar
    {
        get {return m_AVar;}
        protected set { m_AVar = value; }
    }
    public B BVar
    {
        get { return m_BVar; }
        protected set { m_BVar = value; }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
         // SingletonImplementation
    }

    void Start()
    {
        m_AVar = new A();
        m_BVar = new B();
    }
```

At some point in the game someone decides to call my Status.ExecuteSomeAction():

```
    public void ExecuteSomeAction()
    {
          AVar.DoSome();
          BVar.DoSomethingElse();
    }
```

and everything go fine. While at the end by a UIButton.OnClickEvent:

```
    public void ExecuteOnClickAction()
    {
        AVar.Foo();
    }
```

But no matter what AVar result null. Reading left and right I have the feeling that there's something under the hood with those System.Object which I still don't get.

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem myself some time ago.
When the singleton pattern creates a new instance of this class (Status) then the links to the UI-Objects won't be created.

To solve this problem create a class which is responsible for handling the UI. This class will then call your *Status* class.

Another way is to change the singleton pattern to your needs. In my case I simply wrote this:

```
public static Status Instance { get; set; }

public Awake()
{
   Instance = this;
}
```

This may be a bit sloppy because I will get problems if there is more than one instance of this class but it does the job.

Comment: I still don't get the point: why in some part of the code it works, in some others no? Moreover: A and B are not Unity UI classes, why shouldn't be created?

Comment: I almost forgot: B type, which has only a int property, does not suffer of this kind of problem. (A instead uses SceneManager to change scene).

Comment: And mistery over misteries: I added a "sceneCreationTickCounter" increasing it every time I make a new of it and along a check on is null when I use it: bug solved and tick to 1...